# Android returning old, cached web data

Tags: android, http, ftp

I am designing an app that processes customer orders.

My main screen shows a list of all current orders, in a ListView, that it downloads from a text file on my website. It also has a button to make a new order.

When a new order is created, filled, and sent, it updates the text file on the website with a line of data.

After an order is created, I redownload the text file in order to parse it. However, the new data that was uploaded to the text file does not appear for 1-15 minutes on my device. However, when I load the text file from my computer, the text file shows that the order was correctly uploaded.

This error has been encountered by me using both org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient, 2 different URL inputstream, and HttpClient get requests. The behavior of the error is weird that the data is cached for up to 15 minutes, or sometimes it doesn't manifest at all.

Is the cell tower network caching this data somehow? Anyone else encountered this? Is there a workaround or a way to request fresh data?

My 4 methods for downloading the text file were all taken from various examples online and are rather verbose, however if you want to see them I will upload them.

Answer (score 1):

If there is somewhere a transparent proxy which caches the data you should try to avoid caching by setting http headers which disallow it.

E.g. use:

- Etag
- Last-Modified
- Cache-Control: max-age=0, must-revalidate
- Pragma: no-cache